# primeng Table stop unselect when row is expanded

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, selection, primeng-table

I am using primeng Table and this is my p-table

```
 <p-table
        #tableDrag
        [id]="'tblFieldsTab'"
        [value]="fieldsData"
        [lazy]="true"
        [columns]="columns"
        [(selection)]="selectedField"
        [scrollHeight]="'flex'"
        [columnResizeMode]="'expand'"
        responsiveLayout="scroll"
        [scrollable]="true"
        (onRowSelect)="getSubtabList(); selected()"
        (onRowUnselect)="unselected()"
        [class.dragging]="dragging"
        selectionMode="single"
        compareSelectionBy="equals"
        [reorderableColumns]="true"
        dataKey="Criteria"
        (onRowReorder)="onRowReorder($event)"
        expandedRowKeys=""
      >
```

I want to make unselection not possible when I have expanded a row, I have already implemented selection of that row on row expansion but the row gets unselected when the User clicks on the row again.